# Does QuickBlox REST have an API to get total number of messages?

Tags: json, rest, quickblox

Is there a REST API in QuickBlox that gives me the total number of messages sent and received by all users across an entire application?
The /chat/Message and /chat/Dialog are too expensive in terms of network bandwidth and processing speed - they give me all messages or force me to loop through all dialogs, then get all messages.
I'd like something simpler that gives me just the count of messages. Is there anything available in QB?

Answer (score 1):

No. You only can get the total number of dialogs, and loop to get all messages.